# How to filter a fastq file grepping a degenerate pattern?

Tags: python, bash, filter, fastq

I would like to filter a fastq file in order to output only sequences that present a specific pattern ("..........CAA.....GTGG..........", the dot corresponds to a whatever nucleotide A,C,G,T) with its related quality.

I.e. Input file

```
@Reads1
AGCATTTGATATCAAATTTGGTGGATTGGTGTTGTGG
+
AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
@Reads2
ATTATCACCAGGGCAACAAAAGTGGCCATGCATTGAGA
+
AAFFFJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
@Reads3
ATTATCAAAAAAAAACCCTTGGTGGCCATGCATTGAGA
+
AAFFFJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

Output file:

```
@Reads1
CATTTGATATCAAATTTGGTGGATTGGTGTTG
+
AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
@Reads2
ATCACCAGGGCAACAAAAGTGGCCATGCATTG
+
FFJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

Comment: Are you *sure* the output presented is what you want? It doesn't seem to match your description.  The sequence fields in the output have both been truncated relative to the input, and not even in the same way.  Plus, the quality flags for the first entry have not been truncated consistently with the sequence.  If what you present is really what you want, then we're going to need the logic of how that is determined from the input.

Comment: You've tagged both `bash` and `python`.  For which one do you actually want a solution?

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I used the grep command, but I was not able to truncate my output sequences in order to have only the pattern and the related quality.

Comment: Fastq records are represented as multiple lines.  Line-oriented tools such as `grep` are not well suited for processing them.  If you didn't want to perform corresponding truncations on the sequences and qualities then `sed` would be up to the task, but for what you seem actually to want, you probably should use a *bona fide* fastq parser to read the entries, and a matching fastq formatter to output the selected entries, as modified.

Comment: With this command -> grep -B 1 -A 2  '..........CAA.....GTGG..........' input.fastq | grep -v '^--$'  ->  I was able to obtain the sequences matching the pattern. the issue was to truncate only the pattern

Answer (score 1):

There are a plethora of tools available that are specifically tuned to processing FASTQ or FASTA files. However, here is a standard awk program.

We assume the following convention for the FASTQ format.

> A FASTQ record has four line-separated fields per sequence:
>
> - Field 1 begins with a '@' character and is followed by a sequence identifier and an optional description (like a FASTA title line).
> - Field 2 is the raw sequence letters.
> - Field 3 begins with a '+' character and is optionally followed by the same sequence identifier (and any description) again.
> - Field 4 encodes the quality values for the sequence in Field 2, and must contain the same number of symbols as letters in the sequence.

We can use awk to recreate this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{name=1;seq=2;comm=3;qual=0}
     { a[FNR%4]=$0; if (FNR%4) next }
     # At this point we have the full record
     # Perform sequence check and print if accepted:
     match(a[seq],"..........CAA.....GTGG..........") { 
        print a[1]; print substr(a[2],RSTART,RLENGTH);
        print a[3]; print substr(a[0],RSTART,RLENGTH)
     }' file.fastq
```

Comment: It does not work because it does not truncate output sequences in order to have only the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org.txr).

```
$ txr filter.txr data
@Reads1
CATTTGATATCAAATTTGGTGGATTGGTGTTG
+
FFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
@Reads2
ATCACCAGGGCAACAAAAGTGGCCATGCATTG
+
FFJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

Note that, based on the assumption that the corresponding subsequence of the second nucleotide sequence in each section is to be extracted, there is a discrepancy between the value we calculate and the expected data:

```
$ diff <(txr filter.txr data) expected
4c4
< FFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
---
> AAFFFJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ
```

It's also not clear whether multiple matches are expected, with the second sequence being trimmed accordingly.

Code:

```
@(repeat)
@@@heading
@before@{match /..........CAA.....GTGG........../}@nil
+
@other
@  (output)
@@@heading
@match
+
@{other [(len before)..(+ (len before) (len match))]}
@  (end)
@(end)
```